# How to auto cancel deleting while rm asking for confirm?

Tags: macos, bash, rm

Is there something like `rm -f` but auto `n` not auto `y`?
To delete what can be deleted rm not asked and prevent others being deleted. Like files with read-only flag, files opened by other program.
I tried `yes n | rm somefile` not working.

It's OS X 10.11. rm promotes on read-only files.

Seems rm has different default behavior on different platform.

Answers I've tried on OS X 10.11 and Ubuntu 14.04 (not work):

```
rm somefile
rm --interactive=never somefile 
echo n| rm -i somefile
```

Ubuntu log:

```
$ touch somefile
$ chmod 444 somefile 
$ ls -l somefile 
-r--r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Apr 12 06:04 somefile
$ 
$ rm somefile
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘somefile’? n
$ rm somefile
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘somefile’? n
$ 
$ rm --interactive=never somefile 
$ rm --interactive=never somefile 
rm: cannot remove ‘somefile’: No such file or directory
$ 
$ touch somefile                                                
$ chmod 444 somefile                                                 
$ ls -l somefile                                            
-r--r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Apr 12 06:06 somefile
$ echo n| rm -i somefile 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘somefile’? $ ls -l somefile 
-r--r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Apr 12 06:06 somefile
```

@SaintHax's solution

```
for file in $@; do
    [ -w $file ] && rm $file
done
```

works with read only files on platforms mentioned above.

Comment: What's that supposed to do? Nothing?

Comment: @pfnuesel No, it's not nothing. rm ask nothing and just delete a file in most time. Let it delete in most time but answers no while it asked. A file with read-only flag, a file opened by other program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me on my two flavors of Linux.

```
echo n| rm -i *.csv
```

However, -i is always interactive, so it basically negates the command.  If you want to skip anything with the readonly command, I'd suggest creating a function.

```
del() {
   for file in $@; do
      [ -w $file ] && rm $file
   done
}
```

Note, that this only works if the files are not writable by you.

Comment: Not work with 444 files on OS X 10.11. Prompting `remove a somefile?`

Comment: `echo n| rm -i somefile` not working as expected on ubuntu 14.04. Asked for confirming.

Comment: @Al3n I dont' have access to OS X, but I've edited the answer.  I believe this does what you want.

Comment: Tested working with read only files on OS X. Sorry, I just got a downvote of this question and don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--interactive` or `-i` as option in the `rm` command, as stated in the man pages:

> -i     prompt before every removal
>
> --interactive[=WHEN] prompt according to WHEN: never, once (-I), or always (-i); without WHEN, prompt always

Comment: Thanks, there's no such instructions on OS X rm man.  I tried `rm --interactive=never somefile` and got an `a.txt 
rm: illegal option -- -`. The Mac version man rm`-i          Request confirmation before attempting to remove each file,
                 regardless of the file's permissions, or whether or not the
                 standard input device is a terminal.  The -i option overrides
                 any previous -f options.` I'll try this on ubuntu.

Comment: `rm --interactive=never somefile` not work on ubuntu 14.04. Would delete mod 444 file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
rm --interactive=never somefile
```

Comment: That's the same as `rm somefile`.

Comment: Unless you did an alias (like me) `alias rm='rm -i'`

Comment: `rm --interactive=never somefile` is not the same as `rm somefile`. if `somefile` is `chmod -w` then `rm somefile` will still ask interactively. it is also not the same as `rm -f somefile` because if `somefile` does not exists then `rm -f somefile` will silently ignore the error while `rm --interactive=never somefile` will complain with (non-interactive) error message.